# untar a selection of files

Tags: r, tar, raster

I am  trying to untar several .tar files, but I only want some compressed files within the .tar files to be extracted. All the .tar files have the following content in different orders:

```
[1] "README_V4.txt"                                "F182011.v4c_web.avg_vis.tfw"                 
[3] "F182011.v4c_web.avg_vis.tif.gz"               "F182011.v4c_web.cf_cvg.tfw"                  
[5] "F182011.v4c_web.cf_cvg.tif.gz"                "F182011.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tfw"   
[7] "F182011.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif.gz"
```

I only need the `"F182011.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif.gz"` file to be extracted. I tried the following code, but nothing seems to happen:

```
untar_tiff <- function(filename, folder) { 
  dir.create(folder, showWarnings = F)
  list <- untar(filename, list = T)
  untar(filename, files = str_c(folder, "/", list[str_detect(list, "web.stable")]), exdir = folder)
} 

lapply(filenames_list, untar_tiff,
      folder = "TIFF")
```

I think the problem is in the selection of the files to be decompressed (the `file`option in the `untar` function), but I have tried several options without good results.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having was related with a bad understanding of the arguments in the `untar`function.

The code i ran was this one:

```
untar_tiff <- function(filename, folder) { 
  dir.create(folder, showWarnings = F)
  list <- untar(filename, list = T)
  untar(filename, files = str_c(list[str_detect(list, "web.stable")]), exdir = folder)
} 

lapply(filenames_list, untar_tiff,
      folder = "TIFF")
```

As you may note, I remove the complete file path that was stated in the `files`option and change it for the name of the file that I want to extract from the tarball. The reason behind why this worked remains unclear to me, my best guess is that the `exdir`option already put the files in that folder, and the code was only cheking the existence of this files into the .tar file.

If someone can give a better answer it would be great to other people with a related problem.